# Can we print success message/Assertion Result from Response Assertion in BeanShell PostProcessor using Jmeter?

Tags: java, performance, groovy, jmeter

I am using 'BeanShell PostProcessor' to get the request and response data for generating the result file But I am not able to get the asseration result form Response assertion, Here I have added response assertion inside of sampler , i want to print that success message in logs
whether it is failed/pass 
like : Success message/Assertion result - True/False
Please find the screen shot:
[image]
I will be able to print the all data in excel except 'Success Message(pass/fail)(true/false)
Please find the screen shot :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter Test Elements Execution Order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder):

1. Configuration elements
2. Pre-Processors
3. Timers
4. Sampler
5. Post-Processors (unless SampleResult is null)
6. **Assertions (unless SampleResult is null)**
7. Listeners (unless SampleResult is null)

You cannot get [AssertionResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/assertions/AssertionResult.html) from the PostProcessor as the Assertion hasn't been executed yet, you need to switch to a [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html).

Also, [forget about Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/is-beanshell-dead/), since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), the relevant Groovy code to print Assertion results and failure messages to the *jmeter.log* file would be something like:

```
prev.getAssertionResults().each { assertionResult ->
    log.info('Failure: ' + assertionResult.isFailure())
    log.info('Failure message: ' + assertionResult.getFailureMessage())
}
```

Demo:

[image]